# Do I need a Transit visa if I'm Colombian and going to transfer in Toronto, Canada?

Tags: canada, transit-visas, toronto, colombian-citizens

I'm Colombian and need to know, if I'm going to travel from Colombia to Switzerland and transfer in Toronto, do I need a Canadian visa?

Answer (score 4):

> If you need a visa to visit Canada, then you need a transit visa to
>   travel through Canada without stopping or visiting. This is true even
>   if you are in Canada for less than 48 hours. There is no fee for a
>   transit visa. You can apply for a transit visa by filling out the
>   application for a visitor visa (Temporary Resident Visa) and selecting
>   transit visa from the list of options on the form.

From [Do I need a visa if I am travelling through Canada without stopping or visiting?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=420&top=16).

OOps, forgot to mention, [Colombians](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) do need a visa to visit Canada (an eTA if they hold a valid Green Card).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=co&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=00&TR=ca&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required

The fact is, with the exception of passengers connecting to US-bound flights at Toronto terminal 1, Calgary and Vancouver, all transiting passengers will be checked by Canadian immigration - for this most foreigners need a visa or an eTA (depending on nationality)